# Request to database not sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, ajax

Currently, I have the ability to select an option from a drop-down box and that gives me another set of options to choose from. I can then select "Add" and it queries the database and sends a response back. I'm changing it so instead of a drop down, all the information is displayed listed out, however when I try and select "Add" it loads then doesn't send the query/receive anything back. Using the same method in both, why isn't it sending anything to the database through the new method? Also I need to be able to select different options, e.g. Sex - M/F, Subscribed Y/N and have each different one searched into the query if it is selected.

Current code to send

Script (Same for both)

```
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }

$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); } 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
// Variable to hold request
var request;

$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: '300px'});

//$("#distance_slider").slider({});

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#criteria").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    //$("#isajax").val("1");    

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
          url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //console.log(response);
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Current code to choose an option example

```
<form id="criteria" name="criteria">

<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" name="criteria_search">
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" width="75%" align="left"><strong>Add Rule : &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                        <select name="rule" id="rule" onChange="toggletdDisplay(this.form);"> 

                        <option value="email">Email</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right" name="buttonForm" id="buttonForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="PopupContactsCriteria"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="true"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="record" value="{RECORD_VALUE}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="{MODULE_NAME}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="{FORM_SUBMIT}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="{FORM}" />          
                    <input class="button" type="submit" name="addButton" id="addButton" value="  Add Selected  " disabled/>
                </td>   
                <td class="dataLabel" name="instructions" id="instructions" style="display: inline;padding: 50px;"> <p style="color:black;font-size:10px;"><br /> <i> </i> </td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" >Email Address Required?  Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>
                </tr>
```

(Everything is closed, this was just for an example, this works perfectly fine)

This is what I am trying to do now - system loads then does nothing. (Removed drop down to start with, am I missing some data used to query the database as there are many options, this is simplified to one)

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Additional Rules (*Not Required)</button>

<div id="myDIV" hidden="true">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="edit view">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="additional_criteria" name="additional_criteria">

                <table width="100%" border="0" name="additional_criteria">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p><Strong> Additional Rules</strong><p/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" >Email Address Required?  Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" name="buttonForm" id="buttonForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="PopupContactsCriteria"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="query" value="true"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="record" value="{RECORD_VALUE}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="module" value="{MODULE_NAME}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="{FORM_SUBMIT}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form" value="{FORM}" />          
                            <input class="button" type="submit" name="addAdditionalButton" id="addAdditionalButton" value="  Add Additional  " />
                        </td>   
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: change sub,it to button, and in js use .click insteam of submit

Comment: @AhmedSunny sorry, what?

Comment: o sorry typo mistake. make a button of type button with id,  and istead of  $("#criteria").submit ,use $("#button_name").click(). and seriallize your data by  form id, submit cause issue with ajax sometimes

Comment: @AhmedSunny You couldn't give me an example of what you mean using my code briefly could you?